# Docusign grant an access token to service integrations with JWT grant

Tags: docusignapi

i need to grant an access token to service integrations with JWT grant without asking the users to make and to approve access by the application. If possible i need an example. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! PLEASE check (accept) the best answer to your questions. THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this by using administrative consent. It enables the administrator to proactively grant consent on behalf of their users.

You need:

1. The `Access Management with SSO` feature in your DocuSign account.
2. Claim the email domain used by your users. See [doc](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/org-admin-guide-domains) section **To prove ownership of a domain**.
3. Use the Connected Apps feature to administratively grant `signature` and `impersonation` scopes to your application.

Comment: Thanks for your response, can you please explain how to claim the email domain used by our users.